# Prime counting function in Pari GP

Tags: pari

The prime counting function pi(x) computes the number of primes less than x. With Pari being well oriented towards working with prime numbers, I thought this function would be implemented, but I did not find anything in the documentation.

> - Is pi(x) already implemented in Pari GP?
> - If not, is it possible to find the index of a prime? I know the command prime(n) returns the n'th prime? (If it is possible to find this quickly then this combined with precprime could do the trick.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `primepi`, as in:

```
primepi(10^6)
```

(returns `78498`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not manage to find it in the documentation.

Comment: Do you know why this function is slow for large values of n, even if there are enough precomputed primes to go beyond this limit?

Comment: @BeniBogosel I do not know any details. It seems as if GP will only precompute around `10^8` primes (`10^8==primepi(2038074743)` corresponding to `prime(10^8)==2038074743`), even if the default called `primelimit` is much higher than `10^8` at start-up. I base that on your observation that the function `primepi` and the (right-)inverse function `prime` both become slow when you go to large inputs.